# Redis Docker Container Keeps Exiting

Tags: linux, bash, shell, docker, redis

I was testing out a Redis Container built on top of a Centos7 base image.

There is a ENTRYPOINT to a start.sh script and prior to that we are copying four files to the container.

The start.sh script ideally is required to start redisServer.sh and redisCluster.sh. However the container exists almost immediately.

And if i change the ENTRYPOINT to redisServer.sh then the container works without any issue meaning that the redisServer is starting as expected. And also if I exec into the container, i'm also able to successfully run redisCluster.sh without any issues.

*Where exactly i'm going wrong.* *Also how can i print a log back to my host for debugging*

```
COPY redis.conf /home/demo/redis/redis.conf
COPY start.sh /home/demo/redis/start.sh
COPY redisServer.sh /home/demo/redis/redisServer.sh 
COPY redisCluster.sh /home/demo/redis/redisCluster.sh 
ENTRYPOINT [ "/bin/bash", "/start.sh" ]
```

Contents of the other scripts are like below

```
Content of start.sh
---------------------------
#!/bin/bash

bash redisServer.sh &
sleep 10
bash redisCluster.sh &
```

```
Content of redisServer.sh
-------------------------
#!/bin/bash

/usr/src/redis/src/redis-server /usr/src/redis/redis.conf
```

```
Content of redisCluster.sh
--------------------------
#!/bin/bash

printf 'yes' | src/redis-cli -h 10.11.0.1 -p 16000 --cluster create 10.11.0.1:16000 10.11.0.2:16000 10.11.0.3:16000
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just run your `start.sh` script, it will launch a background process, wait 10 seconds, launch a second background process, and exit.  When that script exits, the container will exit too.

In this case, you don't need something so complex.  The `redis-cli --cluster create` command only needs to run once for the whole cluster, and not once per node.  So at the individual container level:

1. Delete the `start.sh` script.
2. Delete the `ENTRYPOINT` line in the Dockerfile.
3. Set `CMD ["/usr/src/redis/src/redis-server", "/usr/src/redis/redis.conf"]` instead.

The tricky bit is creating the cluster, particularly since [the Redis cluster setup doesn't support DNS names at all](https://github.com/antirez/redis/issues/2186).  This is one of the very few cases where manually setting the container-private IP addresses is useful.  (Or if you let Docker set them, you can use a tool like `host` or [this script fragment](https://github.com/antirez/redis/issues/2186#issuecomment-475224158) to find them later.)  You can `docker-compose run` or `docker run --rm` a temporary container, attached to the same network as your Redis containers, that just runs the `redis-cli` command to create the cluster and then exits.

```sh
docker-compose up
docker-compose run redis1 redis-cli -h redis1 -p 16000 --cluster create ...
> yes
```

Comment: I oversimplified the contents of the `redisCluster.sh` script to understand why it is exiting, but i get it now. Basically there is more content in the script.

The `redisCluster.sh` executes a redis-cli only if it meets a condition and the condition is whether the other nodes are up in the cluster and if they are then are they reachable and if yes then is their a cluster setup already present if yes then it will execute a Cluster ADDSLOTS command instead of cluster create which basically is for full cluster setup.